# MS Edge Navbar Toggle Issue

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, microsoft-edge, nav

i tried to have the bootstrap 4 navbar toogler always show on screen and on clicking on it, to have the responsive behavior. Everything works just fine within FireFox or Chrome.

Unfortunately within MS Edge the navbar toogler moves to the side and i really don't know why.

Here is a example:
https://www.bootply.com/b6rsrY0vCN (Opening this within FF or Chrome it works as expected. With Edge just not)

Has someone any clue, why this happens within Edge?

Thanks,
Luc

Comment: Can you share the code? basically edge does support [hover](https://www.caniuse.com/#search=hover) so more info would be helful

Comment: @Eytan oh sorry, is https://www.bootply.com/b6rsrY0vCN not enough?

Comment: Well browsers handle some elements a bit differently. Give your button element(.navbar-brand) width of calc(100% - 50px) instead of the 100px right now

Comment: @Eytan thanks for you reply. Tried your suggestion, but it didn't work. zhi-lv-msft response worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add the fixed Width property for the `navbar` element. Code as below:

```
<nav class="navbar fixed-top" style="width:175px;">
```

Then the result in Edge browser as below:

[image]